# Samba NT_STATUS_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT

Tags: samba, ldap

for a project we have several samba shares configured as following:

```
[global]
   workgroup = <domain name>
   netbios name = <machine name>
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   security = ads
   encrypt passwords = yes
   realm = <fully qualified domain>
   password server = <ldap server ip>

[Share1]
   path = <path>
   ......
```

The idea is that users connecting will be authenticated by the ldap server and every file written by them will be owned by a linux user with the same name. Apart from SAMBA the linux machine doesn't use ldap for anything else.

Everything worked as expected, until something changed on the ldap server and we are now getting the `NT_STATUS_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT` error. We are tying to comunicate with the ldap team but seeing that every other Active Directory authentication works we expect it will be our responsibility to change the samba configuration accordingly -_-"

The guides I see around are pretty much all focused on installing and using an OpenLDAP server on the linux machine, which we don't need, or configuring linux authentication to use LDAP users internally or do complex mappings other than the username, which we also do not need.

We are using samba 4.2, and it is known that upgrading to a more recent version didn't work with the above configuration (even before the ldap server changes).

Are you aware of any other (maybe more correct) way to configure samba to have the requested behavior? What we need is just the LDAP server answering "user auth ok", no user mapping, no machine in the domain, no complex configuration.

Comment: does your samba box added to the NT domain using the NT Server Manager  ?

Answer (score 1):

When you become the member of a domain (such as is necessary for 'security = ads'), a machine account for your server is created in the directory. Your server uses this account for accessing the resources in the domain.

NT_STATUS_NO_TRUST_SAM_ACCOUNT suggests that your machine is having trouble using its machine account (its credentials might have been invalidated for some reason). Leaving the domain and joining it again ("net ads join") should fix this.

Older versions of Samba supported forwarding authentication to a remote server without being a domain member, but AFAICT this no longer exists.